# Cannot target inserted html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a select menu being dynamically inserted that I need to physically target in order to apply css but cannot. How do I get it to register in the DOM?

```
createDropdown: function(oLetter) {
            var dropDwn = create({ type: "select", id: "glossaryWordDropdown", className: "glossarySelect" });
            for (var i = 0; i < oLetter.arWords.length; i++) {
                var oWord = oLetter.arWords[i];
                $('<option />', { value: oWord.id, text: oWord.id }).appendTo(dropDwn);
            }
            $(dropDwn).on('change', this.onDropDown.bind(this));

            //add to the wordHolder box
            var wordHolderElement = this._screen.getElementById("wordHolder");
            wordHolderElement._container.innerHTML = "";
            $(wordHolderElement._container).append(dropDwn);

            $(dropDwn).css('background-color','black');
        }
```

I appreciate any insight. Thanks.

Comment: What is not happening ? What is expected ?

Comment: simply to get a background color value on the element (i could've alternatively just returned a console alert).

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle for that?

Comment: if your function is in a document ready then it will load after the html on the page is loaded and it will be there waiting for you to style. Otherwise it won't be.

Comment: i see. i will try the document ready. this appears in a linked js file...

Answer (score 0):

make a function and write the change function of drop down in that function and then call this function in document ready function . hope this will help you if your change function not working like this .

```
$(document).ready(function() {
bindevent();
});

function bindevent(){
 your change function goes here ...

}
```

Comment: tried this idea (custom event) to target the element but it's not showing... `$('#glossary-container').on('target','.glossarySelect',function(){
    console.log('here!');
    });
    $('.glossarySelect').trigger('target');`